# what happens when you modify an element of an std::set?

Tags: c++, stl, collections, set

If I change an element of an std::set, for example, through an iterator, I know it is not "reinserted" or "resorted", but is there any mention of if it triggers undefined behavior? For example, I would imagine insertions would screw up. Is there any mention of specifically what happens?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place

Comment: How do you propose to achieve this modification, given that the iterator API is set up to disallow it? (edit: It [looks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place#comment2171354_2217889) like back in 2009 there was a defect in the Standard that might not have protected against this, as it does nowadays)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should not edit the values stored in the set directly. I copied this from MSDN documentation which is somewhat authoritative:

> The STL container class set is used
>   for the storage and retrieval of data
>   from a collection in which the values
>   of the elements contained are unique
>   and serve as the key values according
>   to which the data is automatically
>   ordered. The value of an element in a
>   set may not be changed directly.
>   Instead, you must delete old values
>   and insert elements with new values.

Why this is is pretty easy to understand. The `set` implementation will have no way of knowing you have modified the value behind its back. The normal implementation is a red-black tree. Having changed the value, the position in the tree for that instance will be wrong. You would expect to see all manner of wrong behaviour, such as `exists` queries returning the wrong result on account of the search going down the wrong branch of the tree.

Comment: "The set implementation will have no way of knowing you have modified the value behind its back" Actually, as coppro mentions below, you can't modify the value behind its back through normal means, because its iterators are const. That's what they mean by "may not be changed directly".

Comment: I imagine a set containing shared_ptr to my underlying object - then you call through the reference in the iterator to the underlying object to a const function that modifies a mutable member used for sorting. I think that when they say "may not be changed directly" they mean "do not do this kind of crazy thing", not "it is not possible to modify the members"

Comment: in that case the set is *probably* sorted by the address stored in the shared_ptr, not any properties on the object it is using (unless it is using a custom Comparison functor)

Answer (score 5):

The precise answer is platform dependant but as a general rule, a "key" (the stuff you put in a set or the first type of a map) is suppose to be "immutable". To put it simply, that should not be modified, and there is no such thing as automatic re-insertion.

More precisely, the *member variables* used for to compare the key must not be modified.

Windows vc compiler is quite flexible  (tested with VC8) and this code compile:

```
// creation
std::set<int> toto;
toto.insert(4);
toto.insert(40);
toto.insert(25);

// bad modif
(*toto.begin())=100;

// output
for(std::set<int>::iterator it = toto.begin(); it != toto.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout<<*it<<" ";
}
std::cout<<std::endl;
```

The output is **100 25 40**, which is obviously not sorted... Bad... 
Still, such behavior is useful when you want to modify data not participating in the *operator <*. But you better know what you're doing: that's the price you get for being too flexible.

Some might prefer gcc behavior (tested with 3.4.4) which gives the error "assignment of read-only location". You can work around it with a const_cast:

```
const_cast<int&>(*toto.begin())=100;
```

That's now compiling on gcc as well, same output: **100 25 40**.
But at least, doing so will probably makes you wonder what's happening, then go to stack overflow and see this thread :-)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this; they are `const`. There exists no method by which the `set` can detect you making a change to the internal element, and as a result you cannot do so. Instead, you have to remove and reinsert the element. If you are using elements that are expensive to copy, you may have to switch to using pointers and custom comparators (or switch to a C++1x compiler that supports rvalue references, which would make things a whole lot nicer).

Comment: If you had a reference or pointer to the added item, it would certainly be possible to modify the value after you added it. Also you can abuse C++ casting to achieve nasty undefined behavior quite easily.

Comment: @Mark: No, because items are copied when you pass them by value to put them into a container, so there is no way you can get a pointer to them except through an iterator.

Comment: @newacct: iterators give a reference, so you can cast.  But you better know what you're doing.  You might want to change a field that is not used for sorting, but that could change.

Comment: You can also write a value type with const member functions that modify it (perhaps via mutable member variables which are used by the comparator). Not a good idea, but the compiler can't stop you.