# Is the following code using std::set "legal"?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set

I have this code:

```
set<int>::iterator new_end = 
                   set_difference(set1.begin(), set1.end(),
                                  set2.begin(), set2.end(),
                                  set1.begin());
set1.erase(new_end, set1.end);
```

It compiles and runs fine in visual studio. However, in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908949/what-happens-when-you-modify-an-element-of-an-stdset), people stated that a `set`'s iterators are supposed to be `const`. I don't see anything like that in the standard. Can someone tell me where it says that, or if this is well-defined behavior?

If it's not, please provide code that does what I need. Is there a way to do this without creating a temporary set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code violates a couple of the invariants for `set_difference`.  From page 420 of the [Josuttis Book](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/):

- The caller must ensure that the destination range is big enough or that insert iterators are used.
- The destination range should not overlap the source ranges.

You're trying to write back over the first set, which is not allowed.  You need to write someplace other than the source ranges - for that we can use a third set:

```
std::set<int> set3;
std::set_difference(set1.begin(), set1.end(),
                    set2.begin(), set2.end(),
                    std::inserter(set3, set3.begin()));
```

The second argument to `std::inserter` is a hint for where the elements should be inserted.  It's only a hint, however, rest assured that the elements will end up in the right place.  `set3` is initially empty, so `begin()` is about the only hint we can give.

After the call to `set_difference`, `set3` will contain what you tried to make `set1` contain in your original code.  You can go on using `set3` or `swap` it with `set1` if you prefer.

**Update:**

I'm not sure about the performance of this, but if you just want to remove all elements from `set1` that appear in `set2`, you can try:

```
for (std::set<int>::iterator i = set2.begin(); i != set2.end(); ++i)
{
    set1.erase(*i);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

One suggestion to solve it:

```
std::set<int> tmp;
std::set_difference(set1.begin(), set1.end(),
                    set2.begin(), set2.end(),
                    std::inserter(tmp, tmp.begin()));
std::swap(tmp, set1);
```

I can't think of a way to do it without using a temporary set (apart from iterating through the containers and doing erase on individual elements).

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not. From the [SGI STL Reference](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set_difference.html)

1. [first1, last1) and [result, result + n) do not overlap.
2. [first2, last2) and [result, result + n) do not
   overlap.

Also, I'm not sure that begin() can be used as an OutputIterator, as Nikolai N Fetissov pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

The fifth argument to `set_difference` is supposed to be an `OutputIterator`, see [documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set_difference.html).

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard doesn't explicitly say that assigning to set iterators is disallowed, but it does specify for set_difference that "the resulting range shall not overlap with either of the original ranges" (25.3.5.3).

It may have worked for you so far just because you got lucky with the contents of set1 and set2.