# How to tell std::set to 'refresh' its ordering?

Tags: c++, stl

If the value of an element in a set changes the ordering may be no longer correct. As illustrated in this little program:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

struct Comp
{
    bool operator()(const std::string * lhs, const std::string * rhs)
    {
        return *lhs < *rhs;
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::set<std::string*, Comp> MySet;
    MySet mySet;

    std::string * a = new std::string("a");
    mySet.insert(a);

    std::string * c = new std::string("c");
    mySet.insert(c);

    std::string * b = new std::string("b");
    mySet.insert(b);

    for (MySet::iterator it = mySet.begin(); it != mySet.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *(*it) << std::endl;
    }

    // Ouput has correct order:
    // a
    // b
    // c


    *b = "z";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::string * d = new std::string("d");
    mySet.insert(d);    

    for (MySet::iterator it = mySet.begin(); it != mySet.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *(*it) << std::endl;
    }

    // Output no longer ordered correctly:
    // a
    // d
    // z
    // c

    return 0;
}
```

How can I tell the set to 'refresh' its internal sorting?

Comment: The value should _not_ change. The `value_type` should be `std::set<const std:string*>` (though I believe VS doesn't abide by that?)

Comment: The value type is what the user passes, with a top-level const added. If the user passes `std::string*`, the value type will be `std::string* const`. There's no rule forbidding the user to pass something that doesn't enforce the immutability of the value's sorting position; there's just a rule that says that modifying the value in such a way yields undefined behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Very similar subject here (though not quite a duplicate, because you're storing pointers to mutable objects with a custom comparison):

[what happens when you modify an element of an std::set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908949/what-happens-when-you-modify-an-element-of-an-stdset)

Basically, don't do what you're trying to do. Instead, when you want to modify an object that a `set` holds a pointer to, remove the pointer first, then modify the object, then re-insert the pointer.

Answer (score 6):

Simply, you can't. If you place an item into a set, you should not change the item in a way that changes its ordering. If you need to change an item in this way then you need to remove it from the set (set::erase), and reinsert a new item (std::insert) with the new value.

Answer (score 2):

> If the value of an element in a set changes

**Stop!** This cannot legally occur.

`std::set` does not provide any means to do what you're asking, because it's already a pre-requisite that a manual re-order shall never be required.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth point out that if you're using vs 2008, the `std::set` implementation supports non-const iterators, making the code you describe compile successfully using that library.  In other stl implementations (for instance [sgi's](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html)), `set::const_iterator` and `set::iterator` are of the same type which would complain about explicitly setting a new key value.

Comment: Set iterators are const in the standard.  If you try to update the members of a set via an iterator you should get compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

Copy it into itself using a different comparison predicate.

```
std::set MySet();

/* add entries*/

MySet = std::set(MySet.begin(), MySet.end(), Comp);
```

Usually this is used to specify a different comparison operation, eg to sort it using a different part of a stored class/struct.

Comment: NB. This will be far more expensive than removing a single item, modifying it, and then re-adding it.

Comment: If this would lead to a change in MySet, that's already Undefined Behaviour

Comment: `std::set<...> MySet();` is **not** variable.. it's a function declaration!!