# How to update an existing element of std::set?

Tags: c++, stl, set

I have a `std::set<Foo>`, and I'd like to update some value of
an existing element therein. Note that the value I'm updating does not change the order in the set:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <utility>

struct Foo {
  Foo(int i, int j) : id(i), val(j) {}
  int id;
  int val;
  bool operator<(const Foo& other) const {
    return id < other.id;
  }
};

typedef std::set<Foo> Set;

void update(Set& s, Foo f) {
  std::pair<Set::iterator, bool> p = s.insert(f);
  bool alreadyThere = p.second;
  if (alreadyThere)
    p.first->val += f.val; // error: assignment of data-member
                           // ‘Foo::val’ in read-only structure
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  Set s;
  update(s, Foo(1, 10));
  update(s, Foo(1, 5));
  // Now there should be one Foo object with val==15 in the set.                                                                
  return 0;
}
```

Is there any concise way to do this? Or do I have to check if the element is already there, and if so, remove it, add the value and re-insert?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ STL set update is tedious: I can't change an element in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place)

Comment: A little off-topic correction: the `second` member of the pair returned by `insert()` has the opposite meaning. It is `true` when the insertion has actually taken place, and `false` when the element was already there.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Since `val` is not involved in comparison, it could be declared `mutable`

```
struct Foo {
  Foo(int i, int j) : id(i), val(j) {}
  int id;
  mutable int val;
  bool operator<(const Foo& other) const {
    return id < other.id;
  }
};
```

This implies that the value of `val` may change in a logically-const Foo, which means that it shouldn't affect other comparison operators etc.

Or you could just remove and insert, that takes O(1) additional time (compared to accessing and modifying) if insertion uses the position <strike>just before</strike> just after the old one as the hint.

Something like:

```
bool alreadyThere = !p.second; // you forgot the !
if (alreadyThere)
{
    Set::iterator hint = p.first;
    hint++;
    s.erase(p.first);
    s.insert(hint, f);
}
```

Comment: According to the SGI STL implementation, the Amortized O(1) insert is called with the iterator that is just **after** the insertion point.  You'll want to use the element after for the hint, which makes it easier, since if you're pointing at an element, it cannot be `end()`

Comment: @Dave S: yes, C++ library requirements say the same thing, just edited.

Comment: Good answer, but what happens if hint == s.begin()? When you erase the item that an iterator points to from the set you will invalidate that iterator. You need to check for that and insert with s.begin() as the hint in that case.

Comment: That's interesting: according to my drafts of the C++03 and C++11 standards, the meaning of the hint was changed between the two versions: in C++03, the expression `a.insert(p,t)` (where `a` is an associative container, `p` a hint iterator and `t` the value to insert) must have a complexity `logarithmic in general, but amortized constant if t is inserted right *after* p`. This last sentence was modified in C++11, and now states that the complexity should be `amortized constant if t is inserted right *before* p`. (cf. table 69 (C++03) and table 102 (C++11)).

Comment: Like @DaveS said, the new version is much more useful, since it allows "updating" elements much more easily.

Comment: I just found [these comments](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1780.html), which explains very well why the previous version was a mistake.

Comment: @LucTouraille Does this mean there will be different behavior depending if the code is compiled as C++11 or not? Is this correct?

Comment: @user362515: No, the behavior will be the same, it is only the complexity requirements that have changed. The insertion will be performed correctly both in C++03 and in C++11, but the time it takes to do the insertion may be a bit different (I doubt this would be the case on any compiler though).

Comment: @LucTouraille I meant internal behavior. The answer should be updated with your info. Thanks!

Comment: If you see pattern like `std< { k; mutable v; } >` you definitely must use `map< k, v >` instead. `mutable` is dirty workaround.

Answer (score 30):

Don't try to solve this problem by working around the const-ness of items in a `set`. Instead, why not use `map`, which already expresses the key-value relationship you are modeling and provides easy ways to update existing elements.

Comment: True, choose the right container for the right problem.

Comment: Once in a while I encounter this design issues and still did not find a good solution. If my objects are simple, then I can use map to manage the objects. Say my objects uses 5 properties for ordering, I may have to copy them into a tuple as a key. In some situations, mutable strategy is very bad. If any one has a good idea please post here.

Comment: @KeminZhou just use `Boost.MultiIndex` there you can have `std::set` like container and modify it.

Answer (score 10):

Make `val` mutable as:

```
mutable int val;
```

Now you can change/modify/mutate `val` even if `foo` is const:

```
void f(const Foo & foo)
{
     foo.val = 10;  //ok
     foo.id  = 11;  //compilation error - id is not mutable.
}
```

By the way, from your code, you seem to think that if `p.second` is true, then the value already existed in the set, and therefore you update the associated value. I think, you got it wrong. It is in fact other way round. The [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/insert/) at cpluscplus says,

> The pair::second element in the pair is set to true if a new element was inserted or false if an element with the same value existed.

which is correct, in my opinion.

---

However, if you use `std::map`, your solution would be straightforward:

```
void update(std::map<int,int> & m, std::pair<int,int> value) 
{
    m[value.first] += value.second;
}
```

What does this code do? `m[value.first]` creates a new entry if the key doesn't exist in the map, and value of the new entry is default value of `int` which is zero. So it adds `value.second` to `zero`. Or else if the key exists, then it simply adds `value.second` to it. That is, the above code is equivalent to this:

```
void update(std::map<int,int> & m, std::pair<int,int> value) 
{
    std::map<int,int>::iterator it = m.find(value);
    if ( it != m.end()) //found or not?
           it.second += value; //add if found
    else
    {
           m.insert(value); //insert if not found
    }
}
```

But this is too much, isn't it? It's performance is not good. The earlier one is more concise and very performant.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what you're doing (the set elements are not const per se and you're not changing members involved in comparison), then you can just cast away const-ness:

```
void update(Set& s, Foo f) {
  std::pair<Set::iterator, bool> p = s.insert(f);
  bool alreadyThere = !p.second;
  if (alreadyThere)
  {
    Foo & item = const_cast<Foo&>(*p.first);
    item.val += f.val;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of separate hint, use the erase's return value for the next iterator position

```
bool alreadyThere = !p.second; 
if (alreadyThere)
{
    auto nit = s.erase(p.first);
    s.insert(nit, f);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

you can use MAP witch has very fast access to your element if you have KEY . in this case i think using MAP would be better way to achieve fastest speed . STD::MAP