# Iterator issue in VC++ project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: set, visual-studio-2013

I am migrating the visual studio 2008 vc++ projects to visual studio 2013. I am facing c3892 when migrating one of my projects.Here I am providing sample piece of code which reproduces the the error Iam facing in migration.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
    int myints[] = {21,64,17,78,49};
    std::set<int> myset (myints,myints+5);
    std::set<int>::reverse_iterator rit;
    std::cout << "myset contains:";
    for (rit=myset.rbegin(); rit != myset.rend(); ++rit)
        if(*rit==64)
            *rit=90;
    return 0;
}
```

If we execute the above piece of code in vs2013 ,Iam throwing an error

```
Error error C3892: 'std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base>::operator *' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const
```

But if we execute the same piece of code visual studio 2008, Iam not getting any type of errors the build is successful.

I must change the value in my project.
Please provide me the solution how to get rid of this error.

Thanks in advance.
phani

Comment: you r not only migrating to vs13 but under the hood migrating to C++ 11. i am not fully sure about the error. But check the coding standard and changed syntax for c++ 11 once.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you're not allowed to directly modify elements of a set after they've been inserted (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/). If you changed `set` to `vector` in your example, it would compile just fine.

If you want to modify an element from a set, you must erase it from the set and then insert the modified value.

Actually, [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340434/how-to-update-an-existing-element-of-stdset) is identical to yours and has some cool workarounds suggested.