# why does std::set<>::find return a const?

Tags: c++, stl, set, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ STL set update is tedious: I can't change an element in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place)

I want to use a `std::set<>` to count the number occurences of a certain value and simultaneosly sort the objects. For this I created a class `RadiusCounter`

```
class RadiusCounter
{
public:
    RadiusCounter(const ullong& ir) : r(ir) { counter = 1ULL; }
    void inc() { ++counter; }
    ullong get() const { return counter;}
    ullong getR() const { return r;}
    virtual ~RadiusCounter();
protected:
private:
    ullong r;
    ullong counter;
};
```

(the destructor does nothing) together with comparison operators:

```
const inline bool operator==(const RadiusCounter& a, const RadiusCounter& b) {return  a.getR() == b.getR();}
const inline bool operator< (const RadiusCounter& a, const RadiusCounter& b) {return a.getR() < b.getR();}
const inline bool operator> (const RadiusCounter& a, const RadiusCounter& b) {return a.getR() > b.getR();}
const inline bool operator!=(const RadiusCounter& a, const RadiusCounter& b) {return a.getR() != b.getR();}
const inline bool operator<=(const RadiusCounter& a, const RadiusCounter& b) {return a.getR() <= b.getR();}
const inline bool operator>=(const RadiusCounter& a, const RadiusCounter& b) {return a.getR() >= b.getR();}
```

now I want to use it like this:

```
set<RadiusCounter> theRadii;
....
ullong r = getSomeValue();

RadiusCounter ctr(r);
set<RadiusCounter>::iterator itr = theRadii.find(ctr);

// new value -> insert
if (itr == theRadii.end()) theRadii.insert(ctr);

// existing value -> increase counter
else itr->inc();
```

But now the compiler complains at the line with the call to `itr->inc()`:

```
error: passing 'const RadiusCounter' as 'this' argument of 'void RadiusCounter::inc()' discards qualifiers
```

Why is the instance in `*itr` a const here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As addition, it seems you want just

```
typedef int Radius;
typedef int Counter
std::map<Radius, Conunter>theRadii;

...

theRadii[getSomeValue()]++;
```

Answer (score 10):

Because you can't modify elements in a `std::set`.  If you could, it would allow the possibility that it would break the strict-weak ordering invariant, resulting in undefined behaviour.

If you want to modify an element, then you should erase the element, and insert a new one.

Answer (score 1):

As it happens I already answered this question a few hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9452445/766580. Basically, you can't change the value of a `set` element because the `set` has no way of knowing what you changed. You will need to remove and reinsert your modified value if you want to do this.

Comment: Please flag the question as a duplicate if you find something like this. As it stands, your answer isn't really an answer, it's just a link to some place else.