# Why is this iterator const?

Tags: c++, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ STL set update is tedious: I can't change an element in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place)

Why does this code complain that my argument is a const_iterator when it's not declared that way?

```
void foo(std::set<int>::iterator it)
{
  *it=2;
}
```

I get error: assignment of read-only location ‘it.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator* with _Tp = int’

Comment: After reading the link, I understand. I don't like it, but it makes sense.

Comment: They did this because otherwise they cannot maintain "the invaraints" (they cannot guarantee it's still sorted), which would make `set` fail to work.

Answer (score 3):

Because it's a `set`. Sets use const iterators because you can't change the values without messing up the order of the set.

Answer (score 3):

All set iterators are `const`. You can't update the value of a set member by assigning through the iterator. You must `erase` the old value and `insert` a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Because in C++11 set<>::iterator is the same as set<>::const_iterator. I.e. you cannot modify elements inside a set.