# std::set iterator automatically const

Tags: c++, set, constants, std

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ STL set update is tedious: I can't change an element in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place)

I have extracted the problem and changed names and so for simplicities sake.

Basically I instantiate a class and I stock it in a std::set, later on I'd like to have a reference to the class so that I can check its values and modify them...

The simplified code:

```
        MyClass tmpClass;
        std::set<MyClass > setMyClass;
        setMyClass.insert(tmpClass);
        std::set<MyClass >::iterator iter;
        iter=setMyClass.begin();
        MyClass &tmpClass2=*iter;
```

and the error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const MyClass' to 'MyClass &'
```

(I removed parts of the error message, "MVB::Run::" to clear it up too.)

if I add a preceding 'const' to the last line of code then everything works well but then I can't change the value...

Is this normal behaviour and I have to, say, remove the data, change values and put it back again?

I have the feeling that this has something to do with the sorting of the set but I won't touch the variables that are used for the sorting.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I you are certain you `won't touch the variables that are used for the sorting` the you could work around this by using a [const_cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) like this:

```
    MyClass tmpClass;
    std::set<MyClass > setMyClass;
    setMyClass.insert(tmpClass);
    std::set<MyClass >::iterator iter;
    iter=setMyClass.begin();
    const MyClass &tmpClass2=*iter;

    MyClass &tmpClass3 = const_cast<MyClass&>(tmpClass2);
```

Alternatively, you could declare the members of the class that you intend to change as [mutable.](http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/rants/mutable.html)

Comment: You can do this, but it's bad practice.

Comment: @Oliver: having const iterators is quite annoying in case you have heterogeneous lookup and you want to change the non key part. I agree that const_cast's are bad practice but what alternatives are there besides a similar bad practice of using mutable all over the place or taking a performance penalty using erase / insert.

Comment: You can also use a set of MyClass pointers, which are hashable/sortable independent of its variables. (I.e., You can modify its variables through the pointer)

Answer (score 15):

Yes, this is expected.  If you were able to edit the objects already in the set, the applied sort order might no longer apply, leading to undefined behaviour.