# C++ STL Containers and references

Tags: c++, stl, reference

I have a misunderstanding of how does work references, STL containers and Objects.

I previously look for using references in an STL container, but it seems that STL containers are "objects that store objects". But if I want to store objects and modifying them in the container, how can i do it ?

I pasted a small snipet of code illustrating my issue.

```
class MyObject {
    public : 
        int value;

    MyObject(const MyObject& right) : value(right.value) {}
    MyObject(int _value) : value(_value) {}

    bool operator< (const MyObject& right) const {
        return value < right.value;
    }

    void display() const {
        cout << "(" << value << ")  ";
    }
};
```

And in the main section

```
cout << "Creating ... " << endl;
set<MyObject> oset;

for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
     MyObject o(rand() % 1000);
     oset.insert(o);
}
cout << endl;

cout << "Display before ... " << endl;
for (MyObject o : oset)  o.display();
cout << endl;
cout << "Incrementing ... " << endl;
for (MyObject o : oset)  o.value += 1000;
cout << "Display after ... " << endl;
for (MyObject o : oset) o.display();
cout << endl;
```

Since the container does not use references, the incrementation is applied on copies and not the objects.

I tried to use '&' insided the loop i.e.

```
for (MyObject& o : oset)  o.value += 1000;
```

but I had the following error :

error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘MyObject&’ from expression of type ‘const MyObject’

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a reference to assign to the object - by making the loop variable `o` a reference:

```
cout << "Increnting ... " << endl;
for (MyObject &o : oset)  o.value += 1000;
```

*** EDIT ***

**But** because set is an ordered container, it returns const iterators.
So if you need to amend a set perhaps you should consider using another container instead. Perhaps a map?

But if you really ***have*** to change a set - don't do like the code below. It makes valgrind very upset, as Matthieu has pointed out. Why you can't go around erasing elements in a container whilst iterating through that container. Such madness leads to Undefined Behavior.

```
// ===== ATTENTION - NASTY CODE ALERT !! ========**
    for (MyObject &o : oset)
    {
        MyObject oNew = o;
        oNew.value += 1000;
        oset.erase(o);
        oset.insert(oNew);
    }
// =============================================**
```

**A safer solution**

would be to create another set, copy the original set (whilst applying the required changes), then swap the new set to the old one.

Here `transform` applies the lambda function over the entire set, and stores the results in the new `nset` set. `inserter` creates an insertion iterator for the nset container, inserting from nset.begin(). The final transform parameter - the lambda - takes an original set object and adds 1000 to it, returning the new object. Once the transform creates the new set, `swap` then places the new objects in the original container.

```
set<MyObject> nset;
transform(oset.begin(), oset.end(), inserter(nset, nset.begin()),
   [](const MyObject &o) { return MyObject (o.value+1000); });
oset.swap(nset);
```

See this question on [set updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place) for more info.

Comment: if i do so i have the following error :invalid initialization of reference of type ‘MyObject&’ from expression of type ‘const MyObject’

Comment: see updated answer - Note I don't have a c++ 11 compiler to check the code snippet above at the moment.

Comment: -1: Iterating over `oset` while modifying its structure ? I'd like to see what Valgrind has to say... **§ 6.5.4 [stmt.ranged]** implies you are invoking *undefined behavior*.

Comment: In case anyone is still interested the solution has been revised. Thanks Matthieu for pointing out the issue with the original solution.

Answer (score 1):

The incorrect line is `for (MyObject o : oset)  o.value += 1000;`
You should use `for (MyObject& o : oset)  o.value += 1000;` instead

Answer (score 1):

Use a *reference variable* to refer to the object itself:

```
for (MyObject& o : oset)  
   o.value += 1000;
```

Note the '&', which makes the name "o" refer to the object in the collection instead of a copy.