# Modifying elements in std::set

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, std, stdset

I have the following code -:

```
int main()
{
    set<string> s;
    s.insert( "asas" );
    s.insert( "abab" );

    for ( auto item : s )
    {
        cout << item << "\n";
        reverse( item.begin(), item.end() );
    }

    cout << "\n";

    for ( auto item : s )
    {
        cout << item << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output -:

```
abab
asas

abab
asas
```

The elements of the set are not being modified at all by the `reverse()` function.
I suspect that the elements inside a set cannot be modified at all. But, if this is the case, why doesn't the compiler give an error in the first place itself ?

I am using TDM-GCC 4.9.2 with `-std=c++14` flag on Windows 7.

Comment: You are operating on copies of the items, the originals in the `set` aren't changed. Use iterators to manipulate them directly.

Comment: Items in a set are sorted in a particular order. That is why inserting and removing is always relatively fast, no matter how big the set is. You can specify the order you want, but you cannot change it. If the order of the items matters to you use a sequential container such as a vector.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ STL set update is tedious: I can't change an element in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Elements of a `std::set` are `const`. If you want to mutate the elements you need to do insertions and removals to put the container in the state you want.

In your code example:

```
for (auto item : s)
```

gets translated into something like:

```
for (auto iter = s.begin(); iter != s.end(); ++iter)
{
    auto item = *iter; // Copy!
    // loop body
}
```

The loop induction variable `item` is a *copy* of the element from the `set`, not a reference to the actual element in the `set`. As a result, the `set` is not changed. To change a set you need to call a member function of `set`, e.g. `insert` or `erase`.

Changing `item` to `&item` won't help here; if you do this you'll get a compile-time error because the elements of the set are const, so you can't apply `reverse` to them.

Answer (score 5):

This range based loop makes copies of every element in the set:

```
for ( auto item : s )
```

That is why you can modify `item` in the loop without triggering a compiler error.

If you wanted to modify the elements of a container, you'd need a reference. Using this would indeed result in a compiler error because the elements of a set can't be modified:

```
for ( auto& item : s )
{
  // s is a set. You cannot modify item
```

Answer (score 1):

Objects in an std::set are const, since they are used as keys. So you cannot modify objects in set like this .