# What's the issue using iterator here

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

i've just started with c++ stl and i'm unable to figure out the error...your help be greatly appreciated...

```
int count = 0 ;
while (!s.empty()) 
{
    s.erase(--s.end());
    set<int >::iterator it;
    for (it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++) 
    {

        if (*it > 0)
            * it -= r; //*error : expression must be modifiable lvalue
             //r is a constant
        else 
            s.erase(it);
    }
    count++;
}

cout << count;
```

Comment: If `s` is `set` you cannot modify `value_type` by `*it -= r; `, all items in `set` are only-read. By modyfing this element you would reorder all items of set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying elements in std::set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153825/modifying-elements-in-stdset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)'s iterator is constant you cannot modify it.

> The member types iterator and const_iterator may be aliases to the
>   same type. This means defining a pair of function overloads using the
>   two types as parameter types may violate the One Definition Rule.
>   Since iterator is convertible to const_iterator, a single function
>   with a const_iterator as parameter type will work instead.

The elements are constant too you cannot modify them anyhow.

A solution to your problem would be to erase the element you wish to modify and insert the new element you wish to have.

Comment: Why not extract+modify+merge? Less allocations.

Answer (score 1):

If you have made an iterator **Constant** you can not modify its value. It's better that you change your variable type to a simple variable or create any new variable you wish to have.
This might help you
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-modify-a-const-variable-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

@Oblivion has the answer, but I would say it slightly differently.

A `set` is an ordered collection of elements. The order is maintained by the `set`. If you could change the elements of the `set` (via the iterator), then you would break the ordering of the elements in the set, so the iterators provided by the set give you only read access to the elements in the collection.

If you want to "change" the value of an entry in the set, you can erase the old one and insert a new (presumably different) one.