# error: assignment of member in read-only object

Tags: c++

IDEONE:  http://ideone.com/uSqSq7

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int value, position;
    bool left, right;
    bool operator < (const node& a) const
    {
        return value < a.value;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector < node > a(n);
    set < node > s;

    for (auto &i: a)
    {
        cin >> i.value;
        i.left=i.right=0;
    }

    a[0].position=1;
    s.insert(a[0]);

    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        auto it=s.upper_bound(a[i]);
        auto it2=it; --it2;
        if (it==s.begin())
        {
            a[i].position=2*it->position;
            s.insert(a[i]);
            it->left=1;
        }
        else if (it==s.end())
        {
            a[i].position=2*(--it)->position+1;
            s.insert(a[i]);
            it->right=1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (it2->right==0)
            {
                a[i].position=2*it2->position+1;
                s.insert(a[i]);
                it2->right=1;
            }
            else
            {
                a[i].position=2*it->position;
                s.insert(a[i]);
                it->left=1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto i: a) cout << i.position << ' ';
}
```

When I compile this code, I get

`error: assignment of member ‘node::right’ in read-only object`

I think this has something to do with the `const` in `bool operator <`, but I cannot get rid of it as it is necessary to create the set.

Comment: What's the line in the code that produces this error?

Comment: All the lines where I try to change the value of the object to which an iterator is returned using upper_bound. I have added an ideone link. (  http://ideone.com/­uSqSq7 )

Comment: Can you try to replace `auto it = ...`  by the `set<node>::iterator it=...`

Comment: That made no difference, same error.

Comment: Indeed, the type `set<node>::iterator` resolves to a const iterator...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place

Comment: Oh, thanks. Although the value I'm changing is not part of the key. Making it `mutable` solves the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angelika Langer once wrote a piece about this: [Are Set Iterators Mutable or Immutable?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/Cuj/01.SetIterators/SetIterators.html).

You can solve this by defining the `Node` members immaterial for the `set` ordering as `mutable`:

```
mutable bool left, right;
```

(see a [building version in ideone](https://ideone.com/G7ieCg).)

Personally, I would consider a design mapping the immutable part to mutable parts using a `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

Remember that keys in a std::set are constant. You can't change a key after it's inserted into the set. So when you dereference the iterator, it necessarily returns a constant reference.

```
const node& n = (*it);
n->left = 1; //It will not allow you to change as n is const &.
```

Solution:

As Ami Tavory answered, you can declare left and right as mutable.