# Find and update a custom object inside a std::set on C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have created 2 custom structs on my project and each one have a std::set.

```
struct Subject {
        std::string name;
        std::set<SubjectFrame> frames;

        Subject(std::string subject_name);

        void AddFrame(SubjectFrame &frame);

        bool operator<(const Subject &rhs) const { return (name  < rhs.name);}
        bool operator==(const Subject &rhs) const { return (name == rhs.name);}
};

struct Dataset {
        std::set<Subject> subjects;
        std::map<int, std::vector<Subject> > classification_groups;

        Dataset(const std::string ds_path);

        void AddSubject(Subject &subject);
        void GetDSFromFileSystem(const std::string dataset_path);
        void GetClassificationGroups(int number_of_groups_to_create);
};
```

Every time I wanna add some frame to my set 'frames' I call this function:

```
void Dataset::AddSubject(Subject &subject) {
        set<Subject>::iterator it = this->subjects.find(subject);
        if (it != this->subjects.end()) {
                for (Subject fr : this->subjects) {
                        it->AddFrame(fr);
                }
        }   else this->subjects.insert(subject);
}
```

That calls this function:

```
void Subject::AddFrame(SubjectFrame &frame) {
        set<SubjectFrame>::iterator it = this->frames.find(frame);
        if (it != this->frames.end()) {
                if (frame.l_eye_centroid.x != 0) {
                        it->r_eye_centroid = frame.r_eye_centroid;
                        it->l_eye_centroid = frame.l_eye_centroid;
                }
                if (frame.path != "") it->path = frame.path;
                else return;
        }
        else this->frames.insert(frame);
}
```

So, the logic behind an add operation is: I pass an object and check if there's a object with that name already inside my std::set. If yes, I update the existent object with the informations that my parameter object has and the already registered object don't have, if no I insert the object.

I'm getting this errors when I try to compile my program:

> error: no viable overloaded '='
>                                                   it->r_eye_centroid = frame.r_eye_centroid;
>
> error: no viable overloaded '='
>                                                   it->l_eye_centroid = frame.l_eye_centroid;
>
> error: no viable overloaded '='
>                                   if (frame.path != "") it->path = frame.path;
>
> error: member function 'AddFrame' not viable: 'this' argument has type
>   'const Subject', but function is not marked const
>                                                   it->AddFrame(fr);

Someone has any idea what is causing, and how I can solve, these problems?

Comment: You will probably need to define an `operator=` or a copy constructor or both for your custom class.

Comment: A `std::set` doesn't allow you to change the elements as that can mess up the ordering. You need to remove, modify and re-insert it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For std::set, iterator-s are `const`, this is because they are used as key in the `set` which should not be modified to avoid any inconsistencies in strict weak ordering.

One way so solve it is to make the field you want to modify `mutable`, but make sure it is not used in your `set` ordering.

Comment: `iterator` type for `std::set` were only made `const` since c++11. [Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

Comment: @callyalater, this is how the question is tagged.

Comment: That is true. I was just pointing it out so that if the OP wanted to ensure backwards compatibility, he could use `const_iterator` instead.

Comment: TY for your answer @marcinj. But the problem wasn't solved doing this :/ I tried to use: const set<Subject>::iterator it and const set<SubjectFrame>::iterator it ; the errors are the same. I did it right? PS: defining the atributes as mutable I solve the first 3 errors, but the last error continues even if I set atributes as mutable.

Comment: You need to make your function called on iterator const also.

Comment: Actually you might reconsider this, making this function const and adding mutable in your class will make a mess in your design. Removing, modifying, readding element as Galik suggested would be more elegant.