# No matching member for insert on unordered_set

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I tried to insert a `Movie` object to the `unordered_set<Movie>` container, but I got an error saying that there is no such a matching member function. I did something like this

```
void ActorGraph::addActor(string actor_name, string movie_title, int movie_year){
    unordered_map<string, unordered_set<ActorNode>>::iterator con_itr = connections.find(actor_name);
    ActorNode actor(actor_name);
    Movie movie(movie_title, movie_year);

    if(con_itr != connections.end()){
        auto adjSet = con_itr->second;
        unordered_set<ActorNode>::iterator act_itr = adjSet.find(actor);
        if(act_itr != adjSet.end()){
            //in the set
            auto mov_itr = act_itr->movies.find(movie);
            if( mov_itr == act_itr->movies.end()){
                act_itr->movies.insert(movie) //no matching function, while act_itr->movies is of type unordered_set<Movie>
            }
        }
    }else{
        unordered_set<ActorNode> adjSet;
        actor.movies.insert(movie);
        adjSet.insert(actor);
        connections[actor_name] = adjSet;
        cout << "The size is: " << actor.movies.size() << endl;
    }
}
```

My ActorNode is a struct which looks like this

```
struct ActorNode{
    //the name of the actor/actress
    string name;

    /** the movie that this actor/actree participated in
     */
    unordered_set<Movie> movies;

    ActorNode(string n) : name(n){}

    bool operator ==(const ActorNode &other) const;
};


namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct hash<ActorNode>
    {
        size_t operator()(const ActorNode& actor) const
        {
            return hash<std::string>{}(actor.name);
        }
    };
}
```

Movie struct

```
#ifndef Movie_h
#define Movie_h

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Movie{
    string name;
    int year;
    Movie(string n, int y): name(n), year(y){}
    bool operator ==(const Movie &m) const;
};



namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct hash<Movie>
    {
        size_t operator()(const Movie& movie) const
        {
            return hash<std::string>{}(movie.name + to_string(movie.year));
        }
    };
}


#endif /* Movie_ph*/
```

[image]

I have implemented and overrode the operator and make both my Movie and ActorNode struct compatible for using in the key of unordered_set

Here is the repository: 
[Repo](https://github.com/kesongxie/SixDegrees)

---

[**Minimal Reproduction Example**](http://ideone.com/xY8rPd)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

struct Movie{
    std::string name;
    int year;

    Movie(std::string n, int y): name(std::move(n)), year(y)
    {
    }

    bool operator ==(const Movie &m) const
    {
        return year == m.year && name == m.name;
    };
};


namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct hash<Movie>
    {
        size_t operator()(const Movie& movie) const
        {
            return hash<std::string>{}(movie.name + to_string(movie.year));
        }
    };
}
////////////////////

struct ActorNode
{
    std::string name;
    std::unordered_set<Movie> movies;

    ActorNode(std::string n) : name(std::move(n))
    {
    }

    bool operator ==(const ActorNode &other) const
    {
        return name == other.name;
    }
};


namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct hash<ActorNode>
    {
        size_t operator()(const ActorNode& actor) const
        {
            return hash<std::string>{}(actor.name);
        }
    };
}
////////////////////


int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<ActorNode> actors;
    actors.emplace("Gene Wilder");

    auto itr = actors.find(ActorNode("Gene Wilder"));
    if (itr != actors.end())
    {
        // error: no matching function for call to                  
        //  'std::unordered_set<Movie>::insert(Movie) const'
        itr->movies.insert(Movie("Stir Crazy", 1980)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give a minimal complete example. And please give the whole error message.

Comment: Btw: You are missing a `;` at the end of the line with the error...

Comment: Thanks. Unrelated, [do **not** put `using namespace std;` in header files.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?s=1|18.6181)

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig

Comment: Just added a repo, thanks @WhozCraig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you cannot modify key of `set`, cause it can lead to `set` rebuild, but `set` will not be rebuilded, cause you just modify variable, nothing else. So, it is explicitly forbidden.

Definition of iterator in [unordered_set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)

```
iterator    Constant ForwardIterator
const_iterator  Constant forward iterator
```

Comment: I have no idea why I didn't remember this. If I remember right, set iterators (both ordered and otherwise) were made `const` to prevent this very problem (people modifying set containment) in C++11 (it's late here and I'm tired, but I *think* that was when it took hold).

Comment: Good to know about this, thanks, I may try to find some work around

Comment: @KesongXie use a map (ordered or not) instead, mapping the only thing you probably care about (the names) to the related objects. The mapped-to-value is freely modifiable in that case. Worth considering.

Comment: Yes, I might go for an unordered_map, thanks @WhozCraig

Comment: @WhozCraig ye, that is true.

Comment: @KesongXie high-hit question for more info in case you're interested [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place).