# How can i replace element in set?

Tags: c++, set

I want to replace an element in a set.After searching in Google, I came across this function `replace`, but when I used it, it gave me an error

> no member named 'replace' in

What are other ways of updating or replacing an element in set?

Comment: There are probably a few duplicates of that question but you can't replace an item in a set. You have to remove the old item and add the new item. It's not too hard.

Comment: `c++` provide basic functionalities which can be used to form several others like `replace --> remove old + add new`.

Comment: `After searching in Google, I came across this function replace` Seems weird to me, since it doesn't exist in this container. Where did you come across it? Did the site say it was defined for `std::set`? If so, that's an error and should be fixed. The reason that `replace` is not available here is that it doesn't actually make sense, since the container is automatically ordered by its elements, so you can't replace one in-place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ STL set update is tedious: I can't change an element in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place)

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have got to `erase()` one element and `insert()` the new one. `replace` is not defined for `std::set`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/