# Best container for struct with several keys c++

Tags: c++, struct, set, multi-index, boost-multi-index

Given the following struct:

```
struct{
// Keys
int key1;
double key2;
type key3;
...

// Variables to increment
double varibleToIncrement;
...
}
```

What would be the best container to store these records given that I will need to increment the variables of the ones which are already in it (based on all the keys)?

I am currently using a set<> and have set my variableToIncrement to mutable in order to be able to modify it. Would Multi-Index be a more efficient solution?

Thanks in advance!
Max

Comment: This is just a particular case of [C++ STL set update is tedious: I can't change an element in place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2217878/96780). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2221314/96780) sums up the two sensible alternatives you have. I'd go for the key/value split and `std::map`, because it looks much cleaner.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight So far, when I create a record with some keys, it is either added to the set (if not already in there) or only the variableToincrement is changed.

Comment: @DanielDaranas I will check out this answer, thanks!

Comment: @Batmax That shouldn't cause any problems then. If you don't see any efficiency problems with a `set`, don't optimize it prematurely.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight One of my issue is indeed speed... I think that the sorting of that many keys (I sometimes have live 6-7) slow down everything

Answer (score 0):

> One of my issue is indeed speed. I think that the sorting of that many keys slows down everything

Use a hash-based container to avoid sorting. For set use [`std::unordered_set<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).

[This Q&A explains how to make hash and equality functions for use with hash-based containers.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17016175/335858)