# Error binding 'string&' to 'const string' when dereferencing a set iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, set

I'm using C++11 and STL. I have this piece of code:

```
std::set<std::string>::iterator it;
[...]
std::string &str = *it;
```

Compiler throws this error:

> error: binding reference of type ‘std::__cxx11::string& {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string&}’ to ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string’ discards qualifiers

Why is it happening?

Comment: `set` only have `const_iterator`s. erase it, and insert a new element instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ STL set update is tedious: I can't change an element in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place)

Comment: or just add `const` before `std::string`, if you did not want to change the value

Comment: Why are defined iterator if it is actually const_iterator? Yes, I need to modify it. I couldn't find this post. Sorry

Comment: You can't modify an element in a `std::set`; that would upset the set's order. If you need to change it you have to remove it and insert a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keys in a set or map are const. If they were not, the set would not be able to provide its guarantee that elements are weakly ordered on the key. i.e. the would become inexplicably unsorted when users mutated the keys.

The `std::set` iterator dereferences to a key. Keys are (to reiterate) const.

Mutable references cannot bind to const references (language-imposed rule).

Therefore, either:

```
std::string const& str = *it;   // refer to the key
```

or

```
std::string str = *it;          // take a copy of the key
```

Comment: Ok, but why C++ defined iterator if it is actually a const_iterator?

Comment: @class_OpenGL: So that it is easy to iterate over the data. `iterator` alone does not imply mutability

Comment: Ahh okk. Thanks!!

Comment: Or more specifically, `std::set<T>::iterator` and `std::set<T>::const_iterator` both exist to match the structure of all the other container templates where they are *not* identical. Similarly `std::set<T>::key_type` is the same as `std::set<T>::value_type`, and `std::set<T>::key_compare` is the same as `std::set<T>::value_compare`