# Is it safe to modify mutable members of objects inside sets?

Tags: c++, set, c++11, mutable

I was curious as to whether the following scenario is safe.

I have the following class definitions:

```
class ActiveStatusEffect
{
public:
    StatusEffect* effect;
    mutable int ReminaingTurns;
    ActiveStatusEffect() : ReminaingTurns(0)
    {
    }
    //Other unimportant stuff down here
}
```

I then store a group of these inside an std::set as follows:

```
struct ASECmp
{
    bool operator ()(const StatusEffects::ActiveStatusEffect &eff1, const StatusEffects::ActiveStatusEffect &eff2)
    {
        return eff1.effect->GetPriority() < eff2.effect->GetPriority();
    }
};
std::set<StatusEffects::ActiveStatusEffect, ASECmp> ActiveStatusEffects;
```

I mark RemainingTurns as mutable because I want to be able to change it without haing to constantly erase/insert into the set. I.e.

```
void BaseCharacter::Tick(Battles::BattleField &field, int ticks)
{
    for (auto effect = ActiveStatusEffects.begin(); effect != ActiveStatusEffects.end();)// ++index)
    {
           auto next = effect;
            ++next;
        if (effect->effect->HasFlag(StatusEffects::STATUS_FLAGS::TickEffect) && effect->ReminaingTurns > 0)
        {                       
            effect->effect->TickCharacter(*this, field, ticks);
            --effect->ReminaingTurns;

        }
        if (effect->ReminaingTurns == 0)
        {
            ActiveStatusEffects.erase(effect);
        }
        effect = next;
    }
}
```

I'm concerned because it seems possible for this to mess up the ordering within the set, meaning I can't guarantee the set will always be sorted by effect->GetPrority()

If that's true, is there a safe way (such as not have RemainingTurns form part of the key) to do this besides copying, modifying, erasing then inserting what I need to change?

EDIT:

@ildjarn - sorry, I didn't think that mattered. It just returns an int stored within StatusEffect. That int is guaranteed not to change over the runtime of the program.

```
int StatusEffect::GetPriority() const
{
    return StatusPriority;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a case for [`std::priority_queue<>`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/priority_queue.html) container instead; for more complex scenarios, see [Boost MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)

Comment: @sehe: Can a priority handle changing keys without reinsertion?

Comment: How can we possibly know whether `RemainingTurns`' mutability matters when we can't see the implementation of `StatusEffect::GetPriority()`?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: std::priority_queue can't handle changing keys without reinsertion and *can't handle reinsertion either* because it does not allow you to access non-top element at all. Been there, had to reimplement it (implemented Dijkstra's algorithm, which needs one). Boost.Graph has a priority queue that can handle updates, but dug up deep in `details` and it requires that each object has ID suitable as array index, which was blocker for me anyway.

Comment: If you have one key part and one data part, why not use a map?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908949/what-happens-when-you-modify-an-element-of-an-stdset

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing data that affects the ordering of an object will indeed break the invariants of associative containers, but because `ActiveStatusEffect::ReminaingTurns` is not involved in the ordering of `ActiveStatusEffect` objects whatsoever, keeping it `mutable` and modifying its value is perfectly harmless.

> I'm concerned because it seems possible for this to mess up the ordering within the set, meaning I can't guarantee the set will always be sorted by effect->GetPrority()

It's a `std::set<StatusEffects::ActiveStatusEffect, ASECmp>`; how could it sort by any criteria other than that defined by `ASECmp`?

Comment: I was concerned about it breaking the keys, and future insertions not being inserted correctly once that occurs

Comment: @user127817 : But `ActiveStatusEffect::ReminaingTurns` isn't part of the key's identity as far as the standard ordered associative containers are concerned, because it's not taken into account inside of `ActiveStatusEffect`'s ordering. I.e., the only risk you run of breaking something in the future is by changing `ActiveStatusEffect`'s ordering logic to use `ReminaingTurns` somehow.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the key of something in a std::set you are off in Undefined Behaviour land - simple as that. Not only will it "mess up the ordering", but the set will probably stop working correctly altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If the key is unrelated to the actual object, or only a part of it, then you should consider using a map rather than a set:

```
std::map< int, ActiveStatusEffect > m;
ActiveStatusEffect x = create();
m[ x.effect->GetPriority ] = x;      // !!!
```

Other issues with your code is that you should use some encapsulation (user code should not get access to the internals of the class (i.e. members should not be public).