# const references of set elements do not preserve information

Tags: c++, class, c++11, iterator, stdset

I have two friend classes:

```
class Node {
private:
    unsigned id_;
    bool marked_;
    std::set<Node> neighbors_;

    friend class Graph;
    ......

public:
bool operator == (const Node & other) const { return id_ == other.id(); }
bool operator < (const Node & other) const { return id_ < other.id(); }
......
};

class Graph {
private:
    std::set<Node> vertices_{};
    void reach_set_helper(unsigned id, std::vector<unsigned> &reach_set);
    ......
};
```

I am trying to create a function that can first find a specific node in the graph `vertices_`, say node `v`. And then I want to change the `marked_` property of the neighbors of `v`. To find `v`, I have to use `std::find()` method. However, the return iterator of this method does not allow me to change member variables of neighbors. This is what I have tried:

```
Node & s = v;
std::set<Node>::iterator pos = vertices_.find(s);
const std::set<Node> & neighbors = (pos->neighbors_);
for (std::set<Node>::iterator it = neighbors.begin(); it != neighbors.end(); it++) {
    if (!it->is_marked()) {
        reach_set.push_back(it->id());
        it->set_marked(true);
        this->reach_set_helper(it->id(), reach_set);
    }
}
```

Notice here that I have to use `const std::set<Node> & neighbors` because I want to change neighbors in place. But I can't change neighbors of `v` through const iterator `it`, so this method does not work. I have a way to make changes to `vertices_` by erase and copy back through iterator, that's not a problem. But here it is different, I am doing operations on elements of vertices, which is another set.  Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Following suggestions by @walnut, I just changed `marked_` to mutable, and now I'm able to write the following code

```
std::set<Node>::iterator pos = vertices_.find(s);
const std::set<Node> & neighbors = (pos->neighbors_);
for (const Node & nbr : neighbors) {
    if (!nbr.is_marked()) {
        reach_set.push_back(nbr.id());
        Stack.push(nbr);
        nbr.marked_ = true;
    }
}
```

However, this does not solve the problem, as `nbr` in the above code now lose the information of its own `neighbors`, I still can not use this to traverse the graph.

This is so weird because `nbr` is a reference of the original graph node? For example, I cannot even use this to print out my graph!

```
void MtxGraph::print_graph() const {
    const Node & start = *vertices_.begin();
    print_graph_helper(start);
}

void MtxGraph::print_graph_helper(const Node & v) const {
    std::set<Node> neighbors = v.neighbors_;
    for (const Node & node : neighbors) {
        std::cout << v.id() << " => " << node.id() << " => ";
        print_graph_helper(node);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The above code also doesn't work because the reference `node` doesn't preserve neighbors information of the object it refers to.

Comment: I am using `std::set<Node>`. My `operator==` is defined by their `id` number. If `id` are the same, then they are equal. Oh I don't have C++ 17 available, it seems too fancy for me right now. Just wondering if there is a way to get around this in the current version.

Comment: Thanks @walnut, `operator<` is also define using their `id`, smaller `id` has smaller value.

Comment: In that case, does this answer your question? (`std::set` and `std::map` behave the same way) [Modify key of std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785099/modify-key-of-stdmap) or [How to update an existing element of std::set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340434/how-to-update-an-existing-element-of-stdset) or [C++ std::set update is tedious: I can't change an element in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stdset-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place). Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068167

Comment: Are you suggesting to change `Node` from `std::set` to `std::map`? If so, how am I going to have `marked` property in the Node?

Comment: Not necessarily. I am suggesting either one of the methods used in the linked questions' answers (they apply to `std::set` and `std::map` in the same manner): Either make `marked_` `mutable` *or* remove/modify/insert the `Node` *or* separate the class into key-relevant and key-unrelated state in a `std::map<NodeKey, NodeValue>` *or* (in C++17) use `.extract`.

Comment: I've seen that method for `std::set` in the link, they use erase and copy back, which helped me in the other function but is not applicable in this case though

Comment: Making `marked_` `mutable` is the simplest solution to your problem, given that `marked_` does not participate in the key comparator (i.e. `operator<`).

Comment: Yes I saw these links! But `mutable` seems like a great solution, let me try that out!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Also read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52285161/using-mutable-to-allow-modification-of-object-in-unordered-set) for concerns about the `mutable` approach. (Question is about `std::unordered_set`, but applies analogously for `std::set`.)

Comment: Thank you @walnut, you saved my night! You can post your comments below and I'll take it as an answer. Your method is different from everyone else's.

Comment: You should be able to accept my duplicate suggestion. I did intentionally not write an answer, because there are sufficient answers in the linked questions. The `mutable` method is mentioned in all of them.

Comment: Hi @walnut, it still seems to have some problems, could you please be so nice to have another look at my update? Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't really see from the snippets what exactly is wrong with your code now. You need to provide a [repro] and the output it generates. You have a complete working example using the `std::map` approach in the answer section. This is certainly the cleaner implementation.

Answer (score 2):

walnut@ linked some great suggestions in the comments.  Of them, I would prefer the use of `map` over `set` in your particular case, because the map key corresponds to an explicit arc between nodes.  The below fragment shows how this would look in your example (I put your traversal code into `Graph::f`):

```
#include <set>
#include <map>

class Node {
private:
    unsigned id_;
    bool marked_;
    std::map<unsigned, Node> neighbors_;

    bool is_marked() const;
    void set_marked(bool val);
    unsigned id() const { return id_; }

    friend class Graph;
public:
    bool operator== (const Node& other) const { return id_ == other.id_; }
    bool operator< (const Node& other) const { return id_ < other.id_; }
};


class Graph {
private:
    std::map<unsigned, Node> vertices_;
    void reach_set_helper(unsigned id, std::vector<unsigned> &reach_set);
    void f(Node& s);
};

void Graph::f(Node& s)
{
  auto neighbors = vertices_.find(s.id())->second.neighbors_;
  for (auto it = neighbors.begin(); it != neighbors.end(); ++it) {
    if (!it->second.is_marked()) {
        reach_set.push_back(it->first);
        it->second.set_marked(true);
    }
    this->reach_set_helper(it->first, reach_set);
  }
}
```

As you can see above, you can choose to use `it->second.id()` or `it->first` when you need the id, since they will both have the same value.