# What is an alternative set-like data structure when modifying elements is necessary?

Tags: c++, data-structures, set

STL sets are designed so that it is not possible to modify the elements in the set (with good reason, see [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908949/what-happens-when-you-modify-an-element-of-an-stdset)).  Suppose however I have a structure in which only one of the members acts as the key.  Is there an alternative data structure to a set.  I really want exactly the behavior of sets except this inability to modify a field or member which is non-key.

Comment: You could declare the member of your class that isn't part of the key as `mutable`.

Comment: Or better use a map because this way your separate your key from your values.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Except that if the class's `operator<` uses this member in the comparison, it can break `std::set<>`'s requirements.  There's a good reason elements of the set have to be const.  There's no way to really validate that the mutable members are not modified by the ordering predicate.

Comment: Thanks all, especially for the mutable suggestion.  I would not have thought of that.  But I think rewriting to use a map is probably a better choice for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it's time to redesign, considering std::map instead of std::set.

instead of

```
struct A
{
   K key;
   V val;
};

set<A> a;
```

consider

```
std::map<K,V> m;
```

you can then do

```
m[k] = v;
```

Answer (score 2):

A few possibilities come to mind:

1. Adjust your data structures to use std::map instead
2. Use the std::set, but remove the element you want to change and replace it with the updated value.
3. Design and implement a data structure that satisfies your requirements.

I'd look at the first two options as preferable; the last should be used only if you can't adapt your problem or existing STL containers to meet your needs.

Comment: I usually lean toward `map` in this case, I don't even change my data structure, just create a new `Key` structure, which is the key subset of attribute, and use it as a key. Encapsulating the map provides the guarantee that Key and Value have common values on their common attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the non-key as `mutable`, then you would be  able to modify it.

```
struct A
{
   KeyType key;
   mutable NonKeyType nonkey;
   //..
};

std::set<A> aset;
//...

const A & a = *aset.begin();
a.nonkey = newValue; //you can modify it even if the object `a` is const.
```

You've to make sure that `nonkey` is really a non-key; it must not take part in `operator<` comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to enforce that members of the class used in the ordering predicate are not modified.  An modification to members used in the ordering predicate may potentially break the set.

The easy way to trick the compiler into letting you use the set with mutable members is marking the members as mutable:

```
 class Foo
 {
     std::string myVal1;
     mutable std::string myVal2;
 public:
     bool operator<(const Foo& rhs)const {
         return myVal1 < rhs.myVal;
     }
 };
```

Then, you have to **manually** ensure that `Foo::operator<()` never uses `myVal2` in the comparison.  This is possible, but is is a **Bad Idea (tm)**.  You can mark this specific operator with a huge comment, but you can't automatically duplicate this comment into all custom comparison functions (`std::set<>` accepts this as a second parameter).

The real way to achieve what you want is to use a `std::map<>`.  Put the "key" part in the key and the "value" part in the value.