# STD iterators to pointers; getting different types for code that should be equivilent?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

I'm trying to get a regular pointer from an iterator, but a really peculiar thing is happening regarding the types I'm getting.  I'll just post the code, I assume these two snippets are equal to eachother, but tell me if I'm wrong.  The code leading up to the snippets is:

```
CallbackTrigger trigger(triggerParameters);
std::set<CallbackTrigger> triggerSet;
auto result = triggerSet.insert(trigger);
```

Snippet A:

```
auto whatIGet = &(*result.first);  // whatIGet is type:
                    // "const std::allocator<CallbackTrigger>::value_type *"
```

Snippet B:

```
auto arbitraryStep = *result.first; 
auto whatIWanted = &arbitraryStep;  // this is type "CallbackTrigger*"
```

The code that has trouble with this difference and refuses to compile with snippet A, is when I try to push the pointer onto a list

```
std::list<CallbackTrigger*> listing;
listing.push_back(whatIWanted); // compiles fine
listing.push_back(whatIGet);    // error: "cannot convert parameter 1 from 
                               // 'const CallbackTrigger* to 'CallbackTrigger *&&'"
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Where does it cause the compiler to "stop"?

Comment: How can you get a type for `whatIGet` in snippet A, if the compiler "stops"? (and how does it "stop", exactly?)

Comment: Works for me with GCC 4.4.6 and a dummy struct as CallbackTrigger. What compiler? Elaborate on "stop".

Comment: @Cato Jalf - sorry, it compiles the snippets fine.  But later in the code I try to push the resulting pointer onto a list.  I'll amend the question to reflect that.

Comment: @smocking - the compiler is VS2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the c++11 standard:

```
template<class T> class allocator {
  ...
  typedef T value_type;
  ...
};
```

Therefore `const std::allocator<CallbackTrigger>::value_type *` is the same as `const CallbackTrigger*`. Elements of `set<CallbackTrigger>` are of type `const CallbackTrigger`, so that is what you get, when you try getting a pointer directly to elements of the set.

For Snippet B `arbitraryStep` will be of type `CallbackTrigger`, since `*result.first` would be `const CallbackTrigger` and the const is dropped for the type deduction. Therefore `&arbitraryStep` is of type `CallbackTrigger*` (notice the lack of `const`). Also notice, that `whatIWanted` is a pointer to a local variable (`arbitraryStep`), not the object in the set. Therefore using that might not give you the behaviour you want.

Considering this it should be obvious that you need to change the type of your list to `list<const CallbackTrigger*>`.

Comment: Oh no, you're right about the address thing too.  I totally overlooked that, and yes that is hardly what I wanted to do.  Thanks for the explanation.  I guess I can get around this by just using the iterators themselves instead of trying to get the pointers.  edit- or const pointers, those might work too!

Comment: Clairvoire, Take away the auto magic for a bit and replace them with explicit types and you'll see what is going on pretty easily. You're trying to push_back a const CallbackTrigger* into a std::list<CallbackTrigger*> which isn't going to work without doing a const_cast<CallbackTrigger>)(whatIGet)... btw, doing a const_cast here is really dangerous because if you were to modify the CallbackTrigger* pointing to the CallbackTrigger actually residing in your std::set<CallbackTrigger> all hell can break loose (which is what @DeadMG is alluding to, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908949/)

Comment: ceretullis - thanks for the advice!  I normally don't use them, but in this case, I was confused as to what types I was getting from the insert().  And yeah, I'm just going to avoid them altogether here and make a list of the iterators, or of const CallbackTrigger* if that's possible.  I'll admit mixing const and pointers confuses me still, but I'll just have to look that up some.

Comment: @Clairvoire: Personally I'd advocate for `const CallbackTrigger*` instead of iterators, since your 2 containers are less tighlty coupled that way (always a good thing imo). What exactly trips you up about `const` and pointers?

Comment: I'm never sure if the const applies to the pointer itself, or the data that's being pointed to.  (I'm not sure if it matters either, but the CallbackTrigger objects have a member that is changed outside of the set.  That member doesn't factor into the set's sorting predicate though, so it should be safe?)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the contents of a `std::set` through a non-const alias. Any means you may have discovered to achieve this is simply a bug in your Standard library implementation, and mutating it may lead to undefined behaviour.

Your `whatIWant` alias isn't even into the `set`, it's to the copy you made on the stack.