# Is it safe to modify the contents of STL containers?

Tags: c++, stl

This one is pretty basic.

I remember seeing a warning somewhere (I can't find it now) to the effect that you shouldn't directly modify the contents of STL containers, because it might play havoc with the internal record-keeping the container does. From that, it followed that you should use something like boost's ptr_containers whenever you had an element you want modify.

This is essentially all I want to do:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> jambone;

    jambone.push_back(2);
    jambone.front() = 4;
    std::cout<< jambone.front();
}
```

I'm not trying to do anything fancy here with multiple threads or anything.  That should be fine, right?
Would it be any different if it were a container full of objects, and I invoked a mutator on one of them?

Comment: What kind of modifying do you mean? People pass in vectors as C arrays all the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are confusing 2 things about updating containers:

1. `std::set` is not safe to update a value, as that will change the invariants (see [what happens when you modify an element of an std::set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908949/what-happens-when-you-modify-an-element-of-an-stdset))
2. With some containers—especially `std::vector`—you have to be careful if your operations (such as `push_back`) invalidate iterators and you are using iterators that you obtained before the operation.

With your situation, I do not see a problem with what your are doing.

Comment: Ooh, that does make more sense! I'm going to leave the question open for a few more minutes to be sure, but I think you hit the proverbial nail on its proverbial head. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is good.  Note that `vector::push_back` may invalidate iterators *and* pointers to its members.